# C++ setting up "flags"

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Example:

```
enum Flags
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
};

class MyClass
{
   std::string data;
   int foo;

   // Flags theFlags; (???)
}
```

- How can I achieve that it is possible to set any number of the "flags" A,B,C and D in the enum above in an instance of MyClass?

My goal would be something like this:

```
if ( MyClassInst.IsFlagSet( A ) ) // ...
MyClassInst.SetFlag( A ); //...
```

- Do I have to use some array or vector? If yes, how?
- Are enums a good idea in this case?

Comment: Question is very unclear, but you may want to look at std::bitset.

Comment: To clarify: I want MyClass to have any number of the "Flags" enums set. I wanted to know what the best way to set them and check if they are set is. I think I could achieve that with an array: bool flags[5]; flags[A] = true; flags[B]=false; //..., but I doubt that this is the best way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Warning, brain-compiled code ahead!

const int A = 1;
const int B = A << 1;
const int C = B << 1;
const int D = C << 1;

class MyClass {
public:
  bool IsFlagSet(Flags flag) const {return 0 != (theFlags & flag);}
  void SetFlag(Flags flag)         {theFlags |= flag;}
  void UnsetFlag(Flags flag)       {theFlags &= ~flag;}

private:
   int theFlags;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and would there be a way of (un)setting multiple flags at once?

Comment: Add ResetFlag(Flags flag) { theFlags &= ~flag; } and pass Flags.A|Flags.B for example.

Comment: @nobugz: Thanks, I'll add this to the answer, if you don't mind. (Oh, but `Flags.A` isn't C++ syntax.)

Comment: @sub: look at the STL `bitset` data structure.  This should be helpful when dealing with a number of flags (bits) that may not be an even multiple of the processor's native data type.

Answer (score 2):

In C, you set special (non-sequential) enum values manually:

```
enum Flags
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 4,
    D = 8
};
```

It is better for type-safety to use:

```
const int A = 1;
const int B = 2; /* ... */
```

because `(A | B)` is not one of your enum values.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to use an array or a vector, but what you do need is bitwise comparisons.

The first step is to set the numerical value of each flag an exponential value of 2 (ex - 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,etc...), so in binary it would look like 0001,0010,0100,1000 and so forth.

Now, to set or remove a flag, you need to either add it to the Flag variable, or remove it.  An example of checking for flags would like this:

```
if(MyClass.Flags & FLAG_A)
{
    // Flag is set
}

if(!(MyClass.Flags & FLAG_B))
{
    // Flag is not set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `foo` is your bitflag, you can set A on foo by doing:

`foo |= A`

Unset A on foo by doing:

`foo &= (~A)`

And check if A is set on foo by checking if this expression is true

`(foo & A) == A`

But you will have to make sure that the values of A,B,C,D are set up right (0x01, 0x02, ... )